# Merge arrays into array of objects using map

Tags: typescript, object, multidimensional-array, ecmascript-6

I’m trying to merge arrays with values;

```
const headers = ["DATE", "FGH", "DCP", "MRK"];
const values = [["2019-06-12", 106, 125, 122 ], ["2019-06-14", 108, 128, 121]];
```

into array of objects in order to get final output:

```
[
  { DATE: "2019-06-12”, FGH: 106, DCP: 125, MRK: 122 },
  { DATE: "2019-06-14”, FGH: 108, DCP: 128, MRK: 121 }
]
```

using `.map` method;

```
this.mergedValues = this.values.map((val, i ) => 
  headers.map((headerVal, j) => ({
    [headerVal]: val[j]
  })))
```

but mapping of headers is wrong because it puts every item in object;

```
[ { DATE: "2019-06-12”}, {FGH: 106}, {DCP: 125}, {MRK: 122} ],
  ...
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would solve it dynamically similarly to what you have done, but using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) as last term. With [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) you can construct one final object after transforming each element of the each array of values.

```js
const headers = ["DATE", "FGH", "DCP", "MRK"];
const values = [["2019-06-12", 106, 125, 122 ], ["2019-06-14", 108, 128, 121]];

const result = values.map(value => 
  value.reduce((acc, data, index) => 
    ({...acc, [headers[index]]: data}), {}));

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

I will use as follows:

```
values.map((val, i ) => {
  let obj={};
  for(let i=0;i<header.length;i++){
        obj[header[i]]=val[i];
  }
  return obj;
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method to generate the object element.

```
let mergedValues = values.map((val) => headers.reduce((obj, key, index) => Object.assign(obj, { [key]: val[index] }), {}));
```

```js
const headers = ["DATE", "FGH", "DCP", "MRK"];
const values = [
  ["2019-06-12", 106, 125, 122],
  ["2019-06-14", 108, 128, 121]
];


let mergedValues = values.map((val) => headers.reduce((obj, key, j) => Object.assign(obj, {
  [key]: val[j]
}), {}));

console.log(mergedValues);
```